# How to install version from nexus with minor version

Tags: node.js, semantic-versioning

I have many version of my appliction in nexus with versions 1.52.0-xxxxx
the xxxx is different dates
I have also version of 1.53 and 1.54
How I can get the latest 1.52.0-with the latest date without get the 1.53 version and later 
this is my package.json

```
 "name": "client-tests",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "myApp":>="1.52.0".
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the Node.js version Inside a script itself or Inside the command? It's unclear. In the command just write node -version.

Comment: No it is my package.json

Comment: The issue is with the minor version

Comment: the problem is your title. you aren't "getting" any version, you're specfiying which version of a package to install.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get "the latest" of some older version using that setup.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update answer

After getting more information in the comments and after the question got edited, I now see that you need to update the version of a **Node package**, not a version of Node itself as was asked originally.

To get the latest version of 1.52.x but not 1.53.x use:

```
"myApp": "1.52.x"
```

in package.json. You could also do:

```
"myApp": ">=1.52.0 <1.53.0"
```

or:

```
"myApp": "~1.52.0"
```

See the documentation for more info:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

and the the documentation of the `semver` module for even more details:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver

### Original answer

The latest version of Node is not 1.52 but 7.x and soon 8.0 will be released.

To see you re node version run:

```
node -v
```

in the commend line, or test `process.versions.node` on the Node program.

To upgrade see those answers:

- [node 5.5.0 already installed but node -v fetches with "v4.2.1" on OS X & homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180505/node-5-5-0-already-installed-but-node-v-fetches-with-v4-2-1-on-os-x-homebre/37181311#37181311)
- [how to run node js on dedicated server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312651/how-to-run-node-js-on-dedicated-server/41313267?s=3|0.4217#41313267)
- [Run npm as superuser, it isn't a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525238/run-npm-as-superuser-it-isnt-a-good-idea/40525676#40525676)
- [Install Node.js with downloaded binary on Ubuntu Desktop.. Where do the files go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293352/install-node-js-with-downloaded-binary-on-ubuntu-desktop-where-do-the-files-go/42294905#42294905)
- [NPM and NODE command not found when using NVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396941/npm-and-node-command-not-found-when-using-nvm/41397096#41397096)

Comment: maybe I was not clear I don't want to update node.js but to update application from nexus with different versions

Comment: I updated my question sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @SmashingQuasar Thanks for pointing it out. The question was not clear before the update. I updated my answer.

Comment: but I have minor version like 1.52.01012006

Comment: i thought you said it was 1.52.0-xxxxx? that's quite different.

Comment: for example 1.52.0-20170313124211

Comment: yeah you're going to have to specify specifically which one you want. `"1.52.0-20170313124211"`

Comment: so How I can do it ?

Comment: I just told you.